# R plot: Print text on margin in top left corner

Tags: r, plot

I have the following basic code to plot a grid.

```
grid <- expand.grid( pi=seq(50, 95, 5) / 100, mu2=seq(5, .5, -.5) )
pi <- seq(44, 100, .5) / 100
par( mai=c(.05, .05, .05, .05), oma=c(2.9, 2.9, 0, 0) ) # Make room for label
plot( grid, cex=.5, xlab="", ylab="", cex.axis=.7 )
```

How can I plot a text label such as "(A)" in the top left corner as indicated by the red circle?

*Edit: The "(A)" should be printed in regular, i.e., horizontal, reading direction; not vertically along with the y-axis.*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
text(x = 0.44, y = 5, labels = "(A)", xpd = NA)
```

See also `?par` how you can adjust plot margins with `mar`, if you need more space for the text.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mtext` to place text outside of the margins:

```
##Look at the help page for further details    
mtext("A", 2, adj=1, line=2)

##To rotate "A", try
mtext("A", 2, adj=5, las=1, padj=-22)
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: How can I get the "A" to be "regular" reading direction? I.e., adjusted with X-axis? -- I edited my question above to make this clear.